# react native undefined is not an object, but I defined it

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi so I want to pass function to a functional component to execute. But i Get error undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.deleteChat')
Where I made mistake?
I often get this problem when using class components.

CLASS COMPONENT:

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { chats: [], usersData: [], userIDs: [], deletedChat: false };
        this.getChats = this.getChats.bind(this);
        this.deleteChat = this.deleteChat.bind(this);//DEFINED
      }

    deleteChat = chatID => {
        const myId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        let deleteData = firebase
          .database()
          .ref('/chats/' + chatID + '/members/')
          .remove(myId);
        this.setState({ ...this.state, deleteChat: !this.state.deletedChat });
      };

...
return(
    <TouchableHighlight
              style={{ width: 65, height: 50 }}
              title={data}
              onPress={() =>
                TwoButtonAlert(
                  'Do you realy wish to leave conversation?',
                  this.deleteChat(id),
                )
              }
            >
...
```

My functional component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
const createTwoButtonAlert = (title, deleteChat) =>
  Alert.alert(
    title,
    'My Alert Msg',
    [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
        style: 'cancel',
      },
      { text: 'OK', onPress: () => deleteChat },
    ],
    { cancelable: false },
  );

export default createTwoButtonAlert;
```

I have similar method but it runs in componentDidMount() and it works.
EXAMPLE:

```
componentDidMount() {
    var _userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    this.getChats(_userId);
  }

getChats = _userId => {
    let data;
    let usersData = [];
    var readedData = firebase
      .database()
      .ref('chats')
      .orderByChild('members/' + _userId)
      .equalTo(true);
    readedData.once('value', snapshot => {
      data = snapshot.val();

      // const temp = { ...data };
      const filtered = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) =>
        Object.keys(value)
          .filter(value => value !== _userId)
          .filter(value => value !== 'members')
          .filter(value => value !== 'messages'),
      );

      this.setState({ chats: data, usersData: usersData, userIDs: filtered });
      return true;
    });
  };
```

Comment: please try this deleteChat =(chatID) =>  put chatID in braces.

Comment: @SainPradeep does not solve the problem

Comment: Is it possible to create an expo snack that reproduces this issue to share here? In attempting to boil this down to a minimal and complete code example you may find the issue.

Comment: I don't use expo :(

Comment: You don't have to be a user of expo to use their snacks, basically it's a code sandbox for react-native where your code runs in a virtual device. https://snack.expo.io/ It's a way to see your code running and attempt to debug it a little more.

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/8!m5feM3I

Answer (score 0):

Two issues

1. You invoke `deleteChat` immediately when you pass it as `this.deleteChat(id)`, which returns undefined since it is a VOID return
2. Attach it incorrectly in createTwoButtonAlert, i.e. () => deleteChat is improper syntax

Solution, convert to curried function to enclose the id in callback scope

```
deleteChat = chatID => () => {...
```

This will invoke the function immediately still, but this returns a function to be used as the callback.

Use the correct syntax to assign callback

```
onPress: () => deleteChat() // proxied callback
```

or

```
onPress: deleteChat // directly set the callback
```

Comment: None helped, but the error changed to: TypeError _this2.deleteChat is not a function (In '_this2.deleteChat(id)'; '_this2.deleteChat' is undefined

Comment: @Emilis Perhaps `this.setState({ ...this.state, deleteChat: !this.state.deletedChat });` should be `this.setState({ ...this.state, deletedChat: !this.state.deletedChat });` in the callback? Typo, missing 'd', 'deleteChat' vs 'deletedChat'. `deleteChat` is an arrow function so there's also no need to bind `this` to it in the constructor.

Comment: No its not the problem, commented all this.setState(), error stays.